# Associativity of == operator in c++

Tags: c++, associative

I have this snippet of code in c++:

```
std::vector<int> v1;
std::vector<int> v2;
...
if (v1.insert(v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end()) == v1.end())
{
    return 0;
}
```

Which expression will be evaluated first? When debugging, the right side of "==" operator is evaluated first, is this the right behaviour?

Comment: Does [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) help?

Comment: It's undefined behavior. Order of evaluation of operands is not defined by the standard except for a few particular operators (&&, ||, comma, ?:).

Comment: @greg No UB here. Did you rather mean _undetermined_?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, good point.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: What is "undetermined behaviour"? (hint: there's no such thing)

Comment: @Light I rather meant something like _undetermined order of execution_. It's not UB though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: The word you're looking for is "unspecified" (not to be confused with "indeterminate values").

Comment: @Light Ah, yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has nothing to do with associativity (that comes into play in expressions like `a == b == c`). What you're asking about is the order of evaluation of an operator's operands. With a few explicitly listed exceptions, this is intentionally *unspecified* in C++. This means there is no guarantee whether `a` or `b` will be evaluated first in `a == b`.

The exceptions (for which evaluation order is guaranteed), are:

- All arguments to a function call are evaluated before the function call itself (but in an unspecified order).
- The left-hand side of the **built-in** operators `||` and `&&` is evaluated first (and the right-hand side is only evaluated if necessary).
- The left-hand side of the **built-in** operator `,` is evaluated before the right-hand side.
- The condition in operator `?:` is evaluated before the consequent, and only one of the consequents is evaluated.

Notice that the special properties of `&&`, `||`, and `,` cease to apply when these operators are overloaded. This is precisely the reason why it's a *bad* idea to overload these three operators.

Comment: it should be noted that those exceptions are important though, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: @BM I was working on expanding the answer, I hope it's covered now.

Answer (score 4):

You are not asking for the associativity of `operator ==`, but about the [order of evaluation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order). And the order of evaluation is unspecified for this operator, so you have to assume that the order is always that which does not work for you. Split your statement in two lines to be safe.